# App Crashing after loading dependency graph in RN version 60.4

Tags: android, react-native, androidx, react-native-navigation

The App Crashes after 100% loading of Dependency graph. There is no crash while building the App, just only when navigating from Android to React Native and then it will crash.

I already Migrate Android Studio to AndroidX by doing it in Android Studio, I'm also using Jetifier.
Added `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true`.

I also follow the solution here by @guyca https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/5228

Feel free to ask me for more info and what steps I did. Thank you!

MainActivity.js:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;

public class MainActivity extends NavigationActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--This is the added-->
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
    <!--<intent-filter>-->
        <!--<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />-->
        <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />-->
    <!--</intent-filter>-->
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAUqPyPlsIA9EtcsLF6oI832CYNoSLRuvY"
  />
</application>
```

My Environment: package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"test": "jest",
"android": "cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug",
"jetify": "npx jetify"
},
"dependencies": {
"core-js": "^3.1.4",
"jetifier": "^1.6.3",
"lodash": "^4.17.11",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "^0.60.4",
"react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^2.8.1",
"react-native-fit-image": "^1.5.4",
"react-native-image-grid": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.4",
"react-native-maps": "^0.25.0",
"react-native-navigation": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^2.10.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
"react-redux": "^7.0.2",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"rn-bottom-drawer": "^1.4.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
"@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
"babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
"jest": "^24.7.1",
"jetifier": "^1.6.3",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
"react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
},
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native"
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, what Exception do you got? Please add the stacktrace.

Comment: Where can I find the stacktrace?

Comment: Also doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces for native crashes and RN will show the error directly on the screen as far as I remember.

Comment: I tried to run assembleDebug and this is the result Task :react-native-navigation:compileReactNative51DebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: But this is during build? You said build is running fine. However there should be a better error description somewhere above.

Comment: Yea when running build is fine. But when the dependency graph or metro bundle loads 100% then it will navigate to React Native or in the App.js, right? But no, it will crash.